# How to use while loop in Outer Apply - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What I need to do:

- Identify Open jobs for each part from Sales Order based on earliest Due Date
- Condition: List the earliest job/jobs (for a specific part) which satisfy the Sales Order demand .If top job does  not satisfy the quantity needed, pick the next job..

Sales Order Table – Name : **SalesOrder**

```
SO   | Part    |    SO_Qty   |
--------------------------
SO1  | Part1   |    5   |
SO2  | Part2   |    7   |
SO3  | Part3   |    4   |
```

Job Order Table – Name : **JobOrder** - ((All open jobs- sorted on Due_Date)

```
SO  | Part  | JO   | JO_Qty | Due_Date |
-----------------------------------------
SO1 | Part1 | JO1a |    6   | 11/01/16 |
SO1 | Part1 | JO1b |    5   | 11/10/16 |
SO2 | Part2 | JO2a |    3   | 11/01/16 |
SO2 | Part2 | JO2b |    2   | 11/08/16 |
SO2 | Part2 | JO2c |    9   | 11/18/16 |
SO3 | Part3 | JO3a |    4   | 12/05/16 |
SO3 | Part3 | JO3b |    2   | 12/20/16 |
```

**Results Table** (This is what I would like to see..)

```
SO  | Part  | SO_Qty | JO   | JO_Qty | Due_Date |
-------------------------------------------------
SO1 | Part1 |   5    | JO1a |   6    | 11/01/16 |
SO2 | Part2 |   7    | JO2a |   3    | 11/01/16 |
SO2 | Part2 |   7    | JO2b |   2    | 11/08/16 |
SO2 | Part2 |   7    | JO2c |   9    | 11/18/16 |
SO3 | Part3 |   4    | JO3a |   4    | 12/05/16 |
```

What I have tried:

```
 Select OD.*, SQ.jo, SQ.jo_qty, SQ.due_date
 From SalesOrder AS OD
 OUTER APPLY (Select jo, jo_qty, due_date
              From JobOrder as JO   
              Where JO.so = OD.so AND JO.part = OD.part) AS SQ
```

This returns all the matching job orders regardless the job order quantity. That’s NOT what I’m looking for..

**My question**: can I use while loop within sub query to filter the records?

Thank you in advance for all your help..

**Script you can work with:**

```
;WITH SalesOrder AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('SO1', 'Part1', 5),
('SO2', 'Part2', 7),
('SO3', 'Part3', 4)
) as t(SO, Part, SO_Qty)
), JobOrder AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('SO1', 'Part1', 'JO1a', 6 , '11/01/16'),
('SO1', 'Part1', 'JO1b', 5 , '11/10/16'),
('SO2', 'Part2', 'JO2a', 3 , '11/01/16'),
('SO2', 'Part2', 'JO2b', 2 , '11/08/16'),
('SO2', 'Part2', 'JO2c', 9 , '11/18/16'),
('SO3', 'Part3', 'JO3a', 4 , '12/05/16'),
('SO3', 'Part3', 'JO3b', 2 , '12/20/16')
) as t(SO, Part, JO, JO_Qty, Due_Date)
)
```

Comment: is this output valid `SO2|    Part2|  7|  JO2c|   9|  11/18/16|` in the results table ?

Comment: Yes it does. Demand for Part2 SO_qty = 7 . Total qty of the first 2 jobs = 5. Need to pick the next job to satisfy SO demand.  Thank you

Comment: It's easy with SQL Server 2012 and later. With 2008, I'd recommend a cursor over self-joins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it using a recursive CTE - it's a bit long winded, but this is my best effort...

```
WITH j AS
(
    SELECT
     jo.SO
    ,so.Part
    ,so.SO_Qty
    ,jo.JO
    ,jo.JO_Qty
    ,jo.Due_Date
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY jo.SO, Due_Date) AS RowID
    FROM #jobOrder jo
    JOIN #SalesOrder so
    ON jo.SO = so.SO
    AND jo.Part = so.Part
)
,rCTE AS
(
    SELECT
     RowID
    ,SO
    ,Part
    ,SO_Qty
    ,JO
    ,JO_Qty
    ,Due_Date
    ,JO_Qty - SO_Qty AS Diff
    FROM j
    WHERE RowID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
     j.RowID
    ,r.SO
    ,j.Part
    ,j.SO_Qty
    ,j.JO
    ,j.JO_Qty
    ,j.Due_Date
    ,CASE   WHEN j.Part != r.Part OR (j.Part = r.Part AND Diff < 0) THEN
                j.JO_Qty - j.SO_Qty
            END
    FROM rCTE r
    JOIN j
    ON j.RowID = r.RowID + 1
)
SELECT
 *
FROM rCTE
WHERE Diff IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'll give this a try and update you.

Comment: @Hycinth, did this help?

Comment: HotblackDesiato

Comment: HotblackDesiato, Not yet. I'm still working on it.Your solution is great yet it returns the  results under same SO. (SO1). Doesn't differentiate the sales orders. Also I'm still little shady on this CTE and trying to understand the logic without just grabbing the code.  Thank you for not forgetting me..